# What is the best formula for making tabulation sheet and grading system?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a result tabulation sheet of my students using Microsoft Excel. The problem I am facing with the document is that I cannot specify the logical statement like - if cell E2 = 0, then final grade would be F but otherwise would follow other grades according to GPA.

But in my excel sheet it seems the formula is unable to read the cell value and returning the lowest grade of the whole nested `IF` function. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
=IF(AM9<1,"F", IF(AM9>=1, "D", IF(AM9>=2, "C", IF(AM9>=3, "B", IF(AM9>=3.5, "A-", IF(AM9>=4, "A", IF(AM9=5,"A+","Null")))))))
```

Here is a screenshot of my worksheet:

[image: WorkBook Resultsheet]

Comment: Reverse the tests: IF(AM9<1,"F", IF(AM9=5, "A+", IF(AM9>=4, "A", IF(AM9>=3.5, "A-", IF(AM9>=3, "B", IF(AM9>=2, "C", IF(AM9>1,"D","Null"))))))) But a table and vlookup() is easier to control and edit, also the <1 for F and <=1 for D may need checking.

Comment: Also instead of using multiple nested `IF()`s use `VLOOKUP()` or `LOOKUP()` function **(Note the table needs to be sorted from a to z i.e. ascending order)** . That would be easier. Or if you have `SWITCH()`

Comment: This way you could try `=IF(E2=0,"F",IF(AM9<1,"F", IF(AM9<2, "D", IF(AM9<3, "C", IF(AM9<3.5, "B", IF(AM9<4, "A-", IF(AM9<5, "A", IF(AM9=5,"A+","Null"))))))))`

Comment: Yes. Mr. Mayukh your nested IF is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mr. Mayukh, can you help me with another question. I have a cell that needs to show average of all the passed subjects except the failed subjects. Meaning if one subject contains F grade then the average would be ignored from that cell and will continue showing average of other cell values (subject results). Also, I need the IF function for the condition like - IF E2=0, then Average (multiple cells), otherwise show Null.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image]

Formulae:

```
VLOOKUP(D4,$A$3:$B$9,2,1)
```

Edit
So showing the fractional grades being correctly calculated to refute the comment below;

[image]

Comment: Vlookup doesn't work here because the average grade sometimes become like - 4.25 or 3.10, as this fraction is not specified in the selected range of cells, the output shows N/A. I hope I could clear myself.

Comment: @Md.ImranHossain So edited to include a second image showing vlookup working correctly with fractional grades, you need to check what you entered and make sure it is correct.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I cannot specify all the average values in a column and I have to check all cells if one argument fails. In this case I found the solution given above by Mr Mayukh. His IF nested is working like a magic..